# Display validation messages in struts 2

Tags: java, validation, struts2

I have a form in my application in which I want to validate the user inputs. It has a combo box which is populated from db table. So I have to go to the action class first to populate it(for eg: populateFormAction). Then it will go to form.jsp page.

But the problem is at the time of validation. I have set populateFormAction as input result as follows

```
<result name="input" type="redirect">/populateFormAction</result>
```

But when it returned to form.jsp, it doesn't show the validation errors. I think it is because of the use of populateFormAction in between Action handler and form.jsp.

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions to your problem

1. Call the method which is populating
   the combo, efore returning INPUT (if
   there is any validation error). And
   then dont use type redirect, instead
   directly move to your form.jsp. Of
   course, this would be possible if
   you have the populate combo and
   validate methods in the same action
   class.
2. Pass your action errors as parameters to the populateFormAction
   as follows.Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221475/strut2-get-property-value-in-next-action/5242013#5242013)

I m not sure whether there will be 's' after `actionError` or not, so try both

Comment: Hi Anu thanks for your answer. But I felt some doubts with your suggestions. For 1st: I am using the default struts-2 validation not via any methods. For 2nd: The populating values are taken from db, so there may be more values, so I think it is not feasible to add as param in xml

Comment: If you are using validation.xml then ya 1st is not the solution.For 2nd i was talking about passing errors as params not db values in the struts.xml. I found [this link](http://glindholm.wordpress.com/2008/07/02/preserving-messages-across-a-redirect-in-struts-2/) which i think is useful to you

Comment: Is result type "chain" useful in this situation?

Comment: yes ofcourse, but it will show the first action url in the browser after the whole operation not the last one.You can go with it if you dont have any problem with this

Comment: type-"chain" is required for the first mapping only and BTW you never mentioned about *populateEmployee*_Registration mapping earlier. I can help you if you show some code of your class and mappings of both the classes not only input but other mappings also

Comment: But using chain shows error as "Infinite recursion detected" while using <result name="input" type="chain">populateFormAction</result> and "HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name /populateFormAction" while using <result name="input" type="chain">/populateFormAction</result>

Comment: <action name="*Employee_Registration" class="employee.Employee_Registration" method="{1}">
      <result type="redirect">/viewEmployee_Registration</result>
      <result name="failure" type="redirect">/viewEmployee_Registration</result>
      <result name="populated">/Employee_RegForm.jsp</result>
      <result name="viewAdded">/ViewEmpDetails.jsp</result>
      <result name="edit populated">/EditEmpDetails.jsp</result>
      <result name="input" type="chain">/populateEmployee_Registration</result>
     </action>

Comment: The above comment is the content of that particular action class

Comment: First it will go to populateEmployee_Registration to populate combo box in my form, which returns string "populated" then it will forward to Employee_RegForm.jsp file where the validation is required. While submitting that form and if the validation is successful then it will go to viewEmployee_Registration Action. If validation fails the validation returns the string "input" and it will forward to action populateEmployee_Registration to populate combo box again and to show form.

Comment: is '<result name="input" type="chain">populateFormAction</result>' present in the mapping of 'populateEmployee_Registration' action.Can you show me the mappings where the above one is present

Comment: Actually it is populateEmployee_Registration, I generalized it as populateFormAction at the time of asking question.

Comment: Ok.Have you defined result input in populateEmployee_Registration mapping also?If yes what is that mapping exactly?

Comment: <action name="*Employee_Registration" class="employee.Employee_Registration" method="{1}"> . The above mapping is also for populateEmployee_Registration. I am using *(asterik) for wild card mapping. Then whenever a request comes to populateEmployee_Registration it takes the above action and executes the populate() method of its class. populate() method returns string "populated" and calls its corresponding result.

Comment: Oh thats y it is showing "Infinite recursion detected" error.It is hitting the same action same mapping i.e. input again and again. why dont you try writing a separate one just for debugging

Comment: hmm interesting problem then. Have you gone through the link which i gave?I never tried that but it may help

Comment: I haven't tried it, I thought 'result type chain' will solve this problem. I will try the link. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use "MessageStoreInterceptor“ to preserve the messages.