# how to call multiple actions in one request in struts2

Tags: struts2, action

I am using struts2.0.1, I want to get customer info and product info in one request and show them in one jsp, now I have CustomerAction.getCustomer and ProductAction.getProduct already,is there any way I can reuse these Actions and Methods, so I can combine them and show the returns in one jsp? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new action (or at least a new action method) and a new JSP. Fetching the products and customers should be handled by your model classes, so the action should be really simple and quick to create.

Comment: +1 for this, just Create several actions within one class, and move the commonality into private methods in that class. Plain procedural thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Use `result type="chain"` to move from one action to another to a final jsp.You can also use `result type="redirect"` but then you'll have to pass the parameters in the action mapping also [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221475/strut2-get-property-value-in-next-action/5242013#5242013)

Comment: thanks, but if chain, page will be forwarded to result of second action, which is not I want, anyway to call method in one action but don't take the result of the action?meanwhile if three or more action should be executed, should chain and chain? seems not good

Comment: in that case cant you use simple java to declare objects of those action classes and call those methods in this class only

Answer (score 0):

Here you can create two new action declaration in xml file.
1. For product
2. For customer

Chain product to customer

Create only one result page in customer (chained action)

In this result page you can include two jsp previously created.

You can use action chaining in which the chained action gets the complete value stack of previous action and thus the chained action's result page is the final page.

High re-usability can thus be achieved.