# Struts 2 - Persist property value for redirect action

Tags: redirect, struts2

I want to retain a property value after redirecting to a different action. I know that the value will go away since we are navigating to different action (request). But I need to some how that how can I achieve this ?

Here is my code :

```
<action name="save" class="saveAction" method="saveData">
            <result name="success" type="redirectAction">redirectedPageAction</result>
            <result name="successView" >successView.jsp</result>
            <result name="error" >error.jsp</result>
</action>

    <action name="redirectedPageAction" class="month" method="">
        <result name="success">employeesList.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

In save action class I am using addActionMessage(String msg) method to set a value. Also I have getter/setter for the same.

I tried this but didn't get success :

```
    <action name="redirectedPageAction" class="month" method="">
          <result name="success">employeesList.jsp>
               <param name="msg">${msg}</param>    
          </result>
    </action>
```

I want value which was set by adActionMessage(msg) in my employeelist.jsp page. I am getting null pointer struts exception.

Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your property variable with `redirectAction` as a parameter like this

```
<action name="save" class="saveAction" method="saveData">
            <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
               <param name="actionName">redirectedPageAction</param>
               <param name="msg">${msg}</param>
            </result>
            <result name="successView" >successView.jsp</result>
            <result name="error" >error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Also, dont miss to add getter/setter for `msg` variable in your `redirectedPageAction` action

Comment: Thanks for reply.As I specified in my question itself, this doesn't work for me.

Comment: Its not the same thing which you mentioned. I assume you want to pass `msg` variable from your `saveAction` class to `redirectPageAction` class. So, in the `success` result you need to add `type=redirectAction` and specify the action name and `msg` variables as parameters. Isn't this your case?

Comment: The stuff(adding param) you tried is with `month` action class mapping it should be with `saveAction` class mapping with the format i mentioned in my answer. Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5242013/456135)

Comment: Thx for your reply but this doesn't seem to be working for me..! I am not able to get value of msg in jsp.

Comment: Can't say what are you missing but I am successfully using this method in my project

Answer (score 1):

Actions are created per-request. If you don't actually pass anything from the first action to the second, there won't be anything for the second action to retrieve. Getters don't change HTTP mechanics.

If you're interested specifically in messages/etc., use the [MessageStoreInterceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/message-store-interceptor.html), or do it manually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I will surely check the same.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already mentioned that and you know that it will create a new request cycle and Actions and created per request since they work as Data object also ,which means your request/response parameters will be lost.

Now you have few option

1. Try using the Struts2 build in support for this [message-store-interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/message-store-interceptor.html).

This interceptor has been created to store a ValidationAware action's messages / errors and field errors into HTTP Session and is very useful in your use-case.

If you want wider scope either you can store data in the session and retrieve that at later stage or can pass values as query parameters.

Comment: Thanks for reply. storing data in Session may not be feasible as per my needs but another option seems good.thx again...!!!

Comment: @programmer_1 Almost anything that persists data across a redirect uses the session--it is where user-specific data goes. The message store interceptor abstracts the session away, but that's how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this problem before, sometimes you need to show a whole new view after an action and the redirect result does not take into consideration any previous data (http request stuff).
We wanted to create a custom interceptor, but before doing it I found this 
http://www.mail-archive.com/user@struts.apache.org/msg77854.html

It really helped us a lot.

Having said that, what version of Struts 2 are you using? We use Struts 2.2.3 and the parameters passed to the redirectAtion works fine.
Do you have setter and getters in both actions?

Comment: thanx for your reply. but I got my problem resolved using above post.