# Passing parameters in url while redirecting in Struts2

Tags: java, struts2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strut2 - Get Property value in next Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221475/strut2-get-property-value-in-next-action)

I am trying to achieve the following using Struts2

```
response.sendRedirect("Pay.jsp?msg=transfer");
```

This is what I am doing:

```
 <action name="AddPayAction" class="controller.AddPayAction">
            <param name="paraA"></param>
            <param name="paraB"></param>
            <param name="msg">SomeMessage</param>
            <result name="error">/Error.jsp</result>
            <result name="success" type="redirect">/Pay.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

Any suggestions why the above doesn't get redirected as:

```
      Pay.jsp?msg=SomeMessage
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So far the solution that worked for me was

```
 <result name="success" type="redirect">
                <param name="location">/Pay.jsp?msg=${msg}</param>
 </result>
```

where the setters and getters of msg are defined in the action

Answer (score 3):

```
<action name="AddPayAction" class="controller.AddPayAction">
      <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">Pay</param>
        <param name="msg">SomeMessage</param>
      </result>
  </action>

  <action name="Pay">
      <result name="success">/Pay.jsp</result>
  </action>
```

If you want to pass a variables value e.g. `msg` whose getter/setter is declared in `AddPayAction` then use this

```
<param name="msg">${msg}</param>
```

[A similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5242013/456135)

Comment: Tried this method and the example you posted assumes the target destination is an action but the target is a jsp.

Comment: Look at the answer clearly. For the same reason I have declared a separate action-mapping `Pay` to `Pay.jsp`. Also, make sure the result type is `redirectAction` not `redirect`

Comment: Although I have figured out the solution (Thanks to your help). Ill definitely give this another shot. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I think that should be something like:

```
<action name="AddPayAction" class="controller.AddPayAction">
    <result name="error">/Error.jsp</result>
    <result name="success" type="redirect">
        <param name="location">Pay.jsp</param>
        <param name="paraA"></param>
        <param name="paraB"></param>
        <param name="msg">SomeMessage</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

See example at http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/redirect-result.html

Comment: Tried that.. still no progress.

Comment: This method only works when you are forwarding using the default dispatcher

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look to your code, it looks like you just want to end the action in a JSP, so I do not understand why you are trying to do it using `redireciton` type. I recommend to use default redirect type: `dispatcher`

```
<action name="AddPayAction" class="controller.AddPayAction">
    <result name="error">/Error.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/Pay.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Notice that as `dispatcher` is de default type you don't need to write `type="dispatcher"` in the results. So, now, if you want to have variables available in the JSP, you just need to declare those variables in the action with its get/set methods. For example:

```
private String msg;

public String AddPayAction() {

    // your action code

    this.setMsg("my message");

    return SUCCESS;

}

public String getMsg() {

    return msg;
}

public void setMsg(String msg) {

    this.msg= msg;
}
```

Take a look to the [result types](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/result-types.html) available.

Comment: The reason why i am doing redirect is because the action basically changes the database so in order to prevent the user from accidentally changing the data again by doing a REFRESH i am redirecting instead of forwarding