# Struts 2 Redirect with Parameter

Tags: java, struts2

My Action have getters and setters for id. How to pass id as parameter? I tried the code below it doesn't work.

```
    <action name="FBLogin" class="FBLoginAction">
        <result type="redirect">
            <param name="location">https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token</param>
            <param name="id">${id}</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

Comment: possible solution is : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11014348/1085285

Comment: I see. I wasn't able to search it because I used different keyword in search. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

looks like you forgot to add the actionName you wish to redirect to

```
<action name="FBLogin" class="FBLoginAction">
        <result type="redirect">
            <param name="location">https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token</param>
            <param name="id">${id}</param>
            <param name="actionName">"Action to redirect to"</param>
        </result>
</action>
```