# Passing messages from action to JSP in struts2

Tags: struts2, struts, action

I am trying to use `addActionMessage()` and `addActionError()` to pass messages and error from actions (e.g. in `execute()`) to the forwarded page.

In the JSP, I use:

```
<s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
   <s:actionmessage/>
</s:if>
```

to display such messages.

But no message is shown. I am wondering if anyone could give a fix on this problem, or suggest another solution. I am new to Struts and web development, and I am not sure what is a proper pattern for passing messages from actions to pages.

EDIT: action-mapping code and java code

```
<action name="myAddUser" class="org.any.backend.action.UserAdminAction" method="addUser">
  <result name="success" type="redirectAction">myUserAdmin</result>
  <result name="input" type="redirectAction">myUserAdmin</result>
</action>
```

Java code:

```
    public String addUser() throws Exception {
    // check duplicate
    for (User u : userList)
        if (u.getUserName().equals(userName)) {
            addActionError("A user with the same user name already exists. Choose another user name. ");
            return INPUT;
        }
    if (userName != null && !userName.isEmpty() && password != null && !password.isEmpty()) {
        User newUser = new User();
        newUser.setUserName(userName);
        newUser.setPassword(password);
        userList.add(newUser);
        addActionMessage("User " + userName + " added. ");
        return SUCCESS;
    } else {
        addActionError("User name and password cannot be empty");
        return INPUT;
    }
}
```

Comment: post your action mapping and java code

Comment: @anu attached action mapping config and Java code. Thank you.

Comment: When you are using `redirectAction` you can pass the parameters on to the next action.Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5242013/456135)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is right.

Maybe you are using a REDIRECT-ACTION result type, or a CHAIN.
They both will lose action messages and errors, forcing you to put them in session (and clean them once displayed) for this page.

EDIT: I'm assuming that you are using the block

```
<s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
       <s:actionerror />
</s:if>
<s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
       <s:actionmessage/>
</s:if>
```

and not only the posted one, or you will never see the errors, only the messages...

Comment: Yes! I am using redirect-action. That explains it! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use `session.setAttribute(...)` in Action Class. and `<logic:present .... >` tag in jsp. 
hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

As I have seen you are using redirect action, you can still keep the action error/messages using one of the interceptors.

http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1.2/docs/message-store-interceptor.html

Here's an example in the struts.xml

```
    <action name="submit"
        class="com.dummy.SubmitAction">             

        <interceptor-ref name="store">
            <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />

        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">view</param>
            <param name="asnid">${id}</param>
        </result>           

    </action>

    <action name="view"
        class="com.dummy.ViewUserAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="store">
            <param name="operationMode">RETRIEVE</param>
        </interceptor-ref>  
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" >
            <param name="workflow.excludeMethods">execute</param>           
        </interceptor-ref>  

        <result name="success">pages/user.jsp</result>

    </action>
```